# Flutter - Unable to use setState() in TextButton

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Why cannot I use setState in any of my buttons in flutter?
This is my code of the button:

```
TextButton(
                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                fixedSize: Size(
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2, 100),
                              ),
                              onPressed: setState(() {
                                logPage = false;
                              }),
                              child: const Text(
                                "Sign Up",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                              ),
                            )
```

but the setState command is underlined and Android Studio says:
`This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.`

I would like to change the variable and rebuild my app page to get it updated and it should show changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
onPressed: () => setState(() {
  logPage = false;
}),
```

Comment: Thanks! I know about this but it still didn't work. I just realized I'm declaring this variable at the beginning of the widget build and setting it to true so it couldn't change anyway. Now it's fixed. But what does "() => " exactly mean?

Comment: It means a function with arrow syntax, same as `() {...}`, but you can use this if the function consist of a simple statement or another function call.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking `setState()` in the *definition* of your `onPressed:`.  You need to provide a function to be run at a future time, as in a VoidCallback.  It'd look something like:

```
onPressed: () { setState(() { logPage = false; }),
```

Notice that the onPressed is now a function, not the result of calling a function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear build cache :

```
flutter clean
```

an rebuild again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).